# How to upload different images as background to card view inside flat list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Good Day! I am using the API call to fetch the item details. From API I will get only the Item ID, Item Name, Item Desc. I want to give different image as background for the flat list view in card. As of now there are 10 items I am getting from API. And I am having the ten images in my project folder. Where I have stored in array format and imported in my main component. But I can't able to get the different image as background. Any one can help you me out to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

```
//Code to get the images

renderImage = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <ImageBackground source={CardImages[item]} />
    </View>
  );


//Main Component: 

<FlatList
                numColumns={numColumns}
                data={data}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
                  return (
                    <Card
                      onPress={() =>
                        this.props.navigation.push("ItemDet", {
                          data: item,
                        })
                      }
                      style={{
                        margin: 8,
                        borderRadius: 16,
                        width: config.deviceWidth * 0.43,
                        height: config.deviceWidth * 0.54,
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
                        marginLeft: 14,
                      }}
                    >
                      <ImageBackground
                        style={{
                          height: config.deviceWidth * 0.54,
                          width: config.deviceWidth * 0.43,
                          resizeMode: "cover",
                        }}
                      renderImage={this.renderImage}//here is the call for dynamic image background
                      >
                      </ImageBackground>
                      </Card>
                      />
```

Comment: Why do you have an `ImageBackground` inside another `ImageBackground`

Comment: I tried without ImageBackground  initially and didn't work and again tried like this. Inside a card I need to give an ImageBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite weird, so I decided to fix its syntax by my way, hope you can find something helpful here.

```
const CardImages = {
    firstImage: require('./your-first-image.png'),
    secondImage: require('./your-second-image.png'),
    thirdImage: require('./your-third-image.png'),
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      numColumns={numColumns}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
          <Card
            onPress={() =>
              this.props.navigation.push('ItemDet', {
                data: item,
              })
            }
            style={{
              margin: 8,
              borderRadius: 16,
              width: config.deviceWidth * 0.43,
              height: config.deviceWidth * 0.54,
              overflow: 'hidden',
              justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
              marginLeft: 14,
            }}>
            <ImageBackground
              style={{
                height: config.deviceWidth * 0.54,
                width: config.deviceWidth * 0.43,
                resizeMode: 'cover',
              }}
              source={CardImages[item]}
            />
          </Card>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
```